# New Fish-Shell Aliases are ignored

Tags: alias, fish

as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2763014/2891692
i created for days many alias in my config file `~/.config/fish/config.fish`
and it works.

every new alias i add today don't work.

Example of not working alias:

```bsh
alias bla  = "cd ~/Desktop" 
alias bla2  = "ls -a"
```

[image]

but the alias i added before today. for example:
`alias gitStatus="git status"`

[image]

full `~/.config/fish/config.fish` here:

```bsh
function fish_greeting
     echo 'try nr 5'
end
alias bla2  = "ls -a" 
alias gitStatus="git status"
```

each try i update the welcome message. this works

How could i fix this?

#### Error

if used `alias bla  = "cd ~/Desktop"`

```bsh
bla
Command 'bla' not found, did you mean:
  command 'bls' from deb bacula-sd (9.4.2-2ubuntu5)
...
```

if type part of the alias is first red. but its not a error (confused me first)

#### Operating System:

```
Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-41-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Comment: You have spaces around the `=` , does it work if you write the alias with no spaces, like this: `alias bla2="ls -a"`?

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to include that and the _exact_ error you get when you try.

Comment: While it doesn't contribute to your problem, I really suggest you read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71772234/11810933) to that same question on why you should *not* define aliases in your `config.fish`.  That's the "bash/zsh" way of doing things -- Fish has better methods available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`alias` in `fish` takes arguments in one of two forms:

- As two arguments, the name and the code (the csh syntax)
- As one argument with a `=` separating the name and the code (the ksh syntax)

In your case, because you have spaces around the `=`, this passes it as three arguments to alias, which it won't understand.

In fact it should be printing an error:

> alias: expected <= 2 arguments; got 3

So: Do

```
alias bla "cd ~/Desktop" 
alias bla2 "ls -a"
```

or

```
alias bla="cd ~/Desktop" 
alias bla2="ls -a"
```

Comment: found that it works also without the = with many spaces  `alias bla       "cd ~/Desktop"` yes now this error makes since to me `alias: expected <= 2 arguments; got 3`

Comment: Yes, that is how argument passing in shells typically works. Spaces outside of quotes separate words, but how many there are doesn't matter.